# 'initializing': cannot convert from 'Array<int,3>' to 'int'

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cstddef> //for std::size_t

template<class T, std::size_t Size>
class Array
{
private:
    T _data[Size];
public:
    template<class... Args>
    Array(Args&&... vals)
        : _data{ vals... }
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Array<int, 3> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    Array<int, 3> b = { 4, 5, 6 };

    Array<Array<int, 3>, 2> arr = { a, b };
}
```

Everything works as expected for the first two objects (`a` and `b`) of the class.

Then I declare an array of arrays (2D array if you wish). So when the constructor of `Array<Array<int, 3>, 2> arr;` is executed I believe the template parameter `T` will be equal to `Array<int, 3>`. That way we should be able to successfully give `Args&&...` other objects of the same type. Then the parameter pack will expand.

So `Array<Array<int, 3>, 2> arr;` should essentially have a private member:

```
Array<int, 3> _data[2];
```

Apparently not, since I get the error that is in the title.

Comment: Test your code before posting.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath I tested my code and am baffled by the fact that it doesn't work as I expected it. That's why I posted the question. I explained my confusion as best as I could in the actual question.

Comment: No, test the code you've actually posted.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath Okay, that was a typo. My bad.

Comment: Your class lacks a copy constructor. You'll see the same error if you do `Array<int, 3> a = { 1, 2, 3 }; Array<int, 3> b = a;`. This tries to do `_data{a}`, with predictable results.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik In my original class (complete version) I had declared the copy constructor as: `Array(const Array&) = default;`. Changing that to `Array(Array&) = default;` makes everything work as expected. Why would `const` matter here?

Comment: In the first case, the templated constructor is a better match - it doesn't require a qualification conversion. So that's the one picked by the overload resolution. In the second case, both constructors fit perfectly; overload resolution prefers a non-template, other things equal.

Comment: This works: `template<class... Args> Array(T&& first, Args&&... rest) : _data{ first, rest... } {}`. Doesn't require explicitly mentioning the copy constructor. [Live demo](http://rextester.com/GPOX25540)

Comment: This is a bad idea, because you are not enforcing that the initializer list respects the `Size`.

Comment: @VillasV `class = std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args) <= Size>` is omitted from the example. Does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not make much sense of that compile error message, but apparently providing a copy constructor fixes the problem.

I think that because you did not provide a copy constructor, it tries to use the vals... to initialize the class members directly, which then tries to assign an `Array` inside the `int[]`.

Not providing a copy constructor and trying to do any construction by copy results in the same error message:

```
Array<int, 3> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
Array<int, 3> c = a;
```

> main.cpp:17:26: error: cannot convert 'Array' to 'int' in initialization
>            : _data{ vals... }

So my guess is that this weird error message propagates to your list initialization because it also uses copy constructor.